# Who is the Lavot credited on Elvis’ version of ‘My Boy’?

Tags: songwriter, pop-rock

In the album leaflet for *Promised Land* (CD (2000): RCA 07863 67930 2), there are not four, but five songwriters credited with writing ‘My Boy’, listed as Martin / Coulter / Francois [sīc] / Bourtayre / Lavot. Four of these I have found via the Wikipedia listings, and they are Bill Martin, Phil Coulter, Jean-Pierre Bourtayre, Claude François. But the last one I am unable to find, both searching for the song itself and searching for songwriters. Who is this Lavot?

(Bonus points: I am assuming the Synder credited on ‘Spanish Eyes’ is a misspelling of Snyder (which I believe should be Bert Kaempfert; Charles Singleton; Eddie Snyder).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://music.bugs.co.kr/track/69737054?wl_ref=list_tr_08_chart) the writers of 'My Boy' were William Martin, Phillip Michael Coulter, Claude François, Jean-Pierre Bourtayre and [Yves Jacques Lavot](https://www.discogs.com/artist/1699145-Yves-Jacques-Lavot). Lavot's real name is Yves Lavot-Dessca de Brancourt and he also goes by the names
Guy Marfontaine, Pierre Brancourt and Yves Dessca.